# USB network interface not showing up on Pi 3

Tags: networking, hardware

I am trying to attach a network interfaces (Ethernet Port and mobile Broadband) to my Pi through USB. When I do this on my Pi 1 or Pi Zero it shows up and works without a hitch, but with the exact same installation on the same SD card on a Pi 3, the interfaces do not work.

On the Pi 3, they are detected as a USB devices but do not show up when I query using commands like `ip` and `ifconfig`, even `ifconfig -a`.

I noticed that when attempting this on the Pi 3, the output from `dmesg` lacks the lines containing `register 'asix' at usb-xxxx:xx:xx-x.x CDC_Ethernet Device ...` (for the USB Etherne)
`register 'cdc_ether' at usb-xxxx:xx:xx-x.x CDC_Ethernet Device ...` (for the mobile broadband)

If it's relevant, I have removed the Pi 3's Ethernet port in order to slim down its profile.

Why is the same installation behaving differently on different Pis?

Comment: Paste into the question the output of `lsusb` when the ethernet dongle is attached.  If the command is not found, `sudo apt install usbutils`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems for me that you try to use OTG Gadget ether mode. This mode emulates a USB connection as ethernet connection so you can use it like a normal network connection. This only works if the USB port is direct connected to the USB on-board device. Only on a Raspberry Pi Zero and Pi Zero W is it the case. I don't know but it seems also be the case with a Raspberry Pi 1.

A Raspberry Pi 3B has more than one USB port so it uses internal an additional USB hub to split the one USB port from the on-board device. This is the reason why OTG Gadget mode doesn't work with a RPi 3B. It cannot manage a USB hub.

To have a wired ethernet connection with a RPi 3B just use its ethernet port. Btw. this ethernet port is also connected to the USB hub and shares its bandwidth with other connected USB devices.

Comment: You should be able to use a USB ethernet dongle on any model.  Telling someone to just use the eth jack is not really a good answer...

Comment: @goldilocks The question was "*Why is the same installation behaving differently on different Pis?*". Do you mean the side note isn't a good answer because the other end may not have an ethernet port? Using an USB ethernet dongle is of course a better answer if it was asked ;-). Thanks for the idea. I will update my answer ...

Comment: @goldilocks I'm just a bit unsure: where and how do you want to use a USB ethernet dongle in conjunction with a RPi 3B to be used for Gadget mode?

Comment: The OP never mentions gadget mode (`cdc_ether` is [not specific to that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class)).  Why s/he wants to use a dongle on a board that already has an ethernet jack of course remains a mystery...

Comment: @goldilocks Ah.. now it gets clearer. I misunderstood "*attach a network interface (Ethernet Port) to my Pi through USB*". I don't read that to use an USB/WiFi dongle. I read that to use an USB connection to emulate ethernet - what's doable with Gadget mode. And with this I confused `cdc_ether` with `g_ether` [Raspberry Pi Zero OTG Mode](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41).

Comment: Hi, all. Thanks for answering. Regarding using a USB Ethernet dongle on a Pi 3 that already has one, I needed to slim down my Pi 3 and have removed the USB port. Would using mobile broadband connected by USB also be covered in the answer? Should I edit the question to include this?

Comment: @user942937 Yes, please add the additional information to your question.